# Is it normal to have a white fuzzy substance on the seedling of my pepper plant?

Tags: vegetables, seedlings, bell-peppers

I found this on my orange sweet pepper plant seedling. It's kind of like a fuzzy ball. Is it normal?

[image]

Comment: Dispose of it - its succumbed to a fungal infection or some sort of webby infestation, get rid of it in case whatever it is spreads to the others.

Comment: Oh I agree with Bamboo.  Get rid of it carefully, try not to shake it around.  What caused this is what we should be thinking about.  Too much moisture, humidity.  After disposing of this start (the entire plant and little start pot) put a fan an electric fan on your other starts.  Allow these starts to dry out a little bit before watering. Is this in doors?  Why haven't you had a better germination rate...let's look at that if you want to ask another question.

Answer (score 2):

It is likely a damping off infection.  This rots seedlings at the crown and kills them.  To prevent: use sterile media for starting seeds, don't let soil get sodden, provide enough light.

Comment: Stop watering so much, and try not to get the infect plant anywhere near the others as you pull it out. I'd have a piece of cardboard ready to slip under it as soon as I pull it. The plant next door looks happy, and you don't want to do anything to compromise that, such as spread spores or mycelium.